# Proof that parity of composed permutations is equal to the product of the parities of the individual permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This is an exercise from the book Adventures in Group Theory:

> Lemma 3.1.1. Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_n \implies \mathbb{Z}_n$ be a permutation. Then $${\rm sign}(f) = \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{f(i) − f(j)}{i − j}.$$
> Lemma 3.1.2. Let $f$ and $g$ be permutations $\mathbb{Z}_n\implies \mathbb{Z}_n$. $${\rm sign}(fg) = {\rm sign}(f){\rm sign}(g).$$
>
> Ponderable 3.1.2. For $f$,$g$ as in Lemma 3.1.1, we have
> $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{i − j}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{g(i) − g(j)}{i − j}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{g(i) − g(j)}.$$
>
> Use this to prove Lemma 3.1.2.

Here is how far I got:

1. Using Lemma 3.1.1, substitute the right hand side everywhere $sign$ appears in the statement of Lemma 3.1.2:
   $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{i − j}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{f(i) − f(j)}{i − j}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{g(i) − g(j)}{i − j}$$
2. Substitute the right hand side of the given hypothesis for $\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{i − j}$:
   $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{g(i) − g(j)}{i − j}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{g(i) − g(j)}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{f(i) − f(j)}{i − j}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{g(i) − g(j)}{i − j}$$
3. Simplify by removing the $\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{g(i) − g(j)}{i − j}$ factor from both sides of the equality:
   $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{g(i) − g(j)}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{f(i) − f(j)}{i − j}$$

This is the point where I get stuck. I don't know how to continue the proof algebraically, but I suspect that because $g$ is a bijection (by definition) and therefore invertible, and because the left hand side is essentially just a function of $g$, that we can invert $g$ everywhere it appears and thereby complete the proof. I'm not 100% confident in that but I tested it out on a few cases and $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{fg(i) − fg(j)}{g(i) − g(j)}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{f(i) − f(j)}{i − j}$$ seems to hold. In any case, I seem to either be missing some facts or perhaps this is not the approach the book was expecting you to take. Could somebody explain where I went wrong?

Comment: "Ponderable"? ${}$

Comment: Use `${\rm sign}(x)$` for ${\rm sign}(x)$.

Comment: @Shaun Noted, thank you. "Ponderable" is just an idiosyncracy of the book, it basically just means exercise.

Comment: That's quaint. I like it. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $i,j$, $1\leq i\lt j\leq n$, there exist unique $r,s$, $1\leq r,s\leq n$, such that $g(r)=i$ and $g(s)=j$. So the term corresponding to $i$ and $j$ on the right will be the term with $r$ and $s$ on the left of your final equation.

The only potential issue is that $i$ and $j$ are required to be $i\lt j$, and we have no such control over $r$ and $s$. If $r\lt s$, then we are fine,
$$\frac{f(g(r)-f(g(s))}{g(r)-g(s)} = \frac{f(i)-f(j)}{i-j},$$
with $i\lt j$.
If $r\gt s$, then both numerator and denominator are in the "wrong order", so
$$\frac{f(i)-f(j)}{i-j} = \frac{f(g(r))-f(g(s))}{g(r)-g(s)} = \frac{f(g(s))-f(g(r))}{g(s)-g(r)},$$
so the two sign changes cancel each other out.

Thus, every factor in
$$\prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n} \frac{f(i)-f(j)}{i-j}$$
appears in
$$\prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n}\frac{f(g(i))-f(g(j))}{g(i)-g(j)}.$$
Moreover, different pairs $(i,j)$ yield different pairs $(r,s)$ because $g$ is a bijection, so the two products yield the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite able to follow everything you said here. Do you think you could eIaborate a little? Since we have no freedom in choice of $r$ and $s$ here and they are required to be equal to $i$ and $j$, I don't see how $r$ could ever be greater than $s$. Also, what do you mean What do you mean "the two sign changes cancel each other out"? I didn't understand the equation directly above that line, the two rightmost terms are only equal if $r = s$ aren't they?

Comment: @Bridge: $r$ and $s$ are not equal to $i$ and $j$. $r=g^{-1}(i)$ and $s=g^{-1}(j)$. If, for example, $g$ is the permuation $(1234)$, and you have $i=1$, $j=4$, then $r=4$ and $s=3$, so $r$ is greater than $s$. For that $g$, the factor $\frac{f(1)-f(4)}{1-4}$ corresponds to the factor $\frac{f(g(4))-f(g(3))}{4-3}$. But that factor isn't in the second product; the factor in the second product is $\frac{f(g(3))-f(g(4))}{3-4}$ (because you need the first index smaller than the second). Switching the order in the numerator is a sign change, switching the order in the denominator another sign change

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer now.